# Why is my fadeOut not working?

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

Here's my code...why is my fadeOut not working?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!  The site is:  http://174.120.235.57/~phvne/

```
    $j=jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $j("#nav ul").css({display: "none"});

     $j("#nav li:has(ul) > a").append(" »");
     $j("#nav li > ul > a > span").text("");

     $j("#nav li").hover(function(){
     $j(this).find("ul:first").stop(true,true).fadeIn('medium');
     },
     function(){
     $j(this).find("ul:first").stop(true,true).fadeOut('medium');
     });
});
```

Comment: It works fine for me in Firefox. Which browser are you using? Try Ctrl + F5 to clear your cache and download the latest JS file.

Comment: faedout only works for me on the first "join us" menu in FF, not at all in Chrome

Comment: try taking out the stop() and see if that works. might be losing its state

Comment: I tried taking out the stop() with no luck...thanks though!!!  The weird thing is this works with a normal html/css page but this is a WordPress theme I am building and it doesn't work quite right...thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're loading both jQuery 1.6 and 1.6.2. Also, I'm not sure whether 'medium' exists, try 'slow' or a duration in milliseconds.

Comment: I took out my jQuery call I had in the header.  The slider plugin must be brining in jQuery 1.6.  I also changed 'medium' to 'slow'.  Unfortunately it still is not working...thank you though!!!

Comment: FYI - You're right that "medium" doesn't exist, although when jQuery doesn't get a number or a recognized string, it uses its default speed. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/effects.js#L327-328

Comment: Right, these two issues did not cause the problem, but better to fix them anyway. The real cause was the display:none style on your ul elements, because it makes stop() reset the style to display:none (see wdm's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your CSS...

```
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wdm is right, you're setting `display:none` on the ul elements in style.css:

```
#nav ul { display: none; ...
```

Eiter remove this and call

```
$("#nav ul").hide();
```

in your dropdown.js. This would also follow the unobtrusive JavaScript approach.

If you really want to leave it in, then you must call

```
$("#nav ul").css('display', 'block').hide();
```

in your dropdown.js. But then your menus are only navigable when JavaScript is activated.